# multiple subscription enabling with single apple id

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, in-app

I need to add in-app subscriptions in my app . In that module users can able to pay for the subscriptions using in-app purchases.I need to know , whether users can pay for multiple subscriptions with single app store account?

I need an solution, whether the users can subscribe more than one subscription with same apple account for same subscription.